# How to apply code to multiple Excel workbooks/sheets

Tags: r, excel, loops, csv, tidyverse

I have three different Excel workbooks with 6 Sheets (tabs) each with patient data.
The names are all in the same position for all files and have long names:
ie "2: NIH-IN NIH-IN-99-D99 MDSC Panel NIH 2-99-99"

I have used the following code to remove the extra labeling and get just the name I want (NIH-IN-##)

```
#Load Data 
test <- read.csv("C:/Users/####/Desktop/test.csv")
View(test)

#Take original and remove later chunk following "D" (day)   
df<-separate(test, Sample, c("Keep", "Disc"), "-D", extra = "merge")  

#Split both IN and OUT 
df2<-separate(df, Keep, c("Dont Need", "Need"), sep= "(['NIH-IN '\\'NIH-OUT '\\])", extra = "merge") 
df2<-separate(df2, Need, c("Dont Need", "Need"), " ", extra = "merge")
```

I am wondering how I can apply this code so that it goes through my three Excel workbooks and (if possible) through each Sheet/tab in each one.

I am very new to coding so please excuse any mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a loop that runs your code 18 times? You'll want to store your results in a list.

```
results <- list()
i <- 1

for (filename in c("filename1", "filename2", "filename3")) {
x <- read.csv(filename)
x <- separate(...)
x <- separate(...)
x <- separate(...)
results[i] <- x
i <- i + 1
}
```

Comment: I think so. I have my code and am looking for a way that I can tell it what to run on as opposed to having to upload each file individually, run the code, and export. Also, what is the purpose of the i <- i + 1 at the end of that loop?

Comment: I am currently exporting it as a xlsx file and manually incorporating it back into the excel file I need edited.

Comment: the i <- i + 1 is a counter. the first file will be stored in results[1], second file in results[2], etc. at the end of the loop, you have one list object named results with all tables in it.

Comment: what is the code you are using to "export"? we can incorporate that into the loop as well. right now, the code I am showing you just reads and stores the 18 files, but we can make it export data 18 times as well.